# How to change a url in Joomla

Tags: url, joomla2.5

I am working in Joomla2.5 site. I want to change the url

```
http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quates/
```

to

```
http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quotes/
                                         ^
```

How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL is created by Joomla automatically, based on the name of the component.

If this is a custom written component, you just need to rename the folder components/com_quates/ to components/com_quotes and the URL will be correctly spelled.

Note that you will also need to update all references to com_quates in your PHP code or it will break your component.